# issue in getting id value from the url in actionView yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to pass the id from the URL using the get method, but when I try to get it with actionView in the controllers. When I try to echo the id to check, if it passes the correct id from the URL. the value is always my controller ID. here is my view which passes the id when I click on delete button :

```
<?php
  foreach($twit as $twits){
?>


<header class="text-right">
    <div class="comment-user"> سبحان باقری <i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
    <time class="comment-date" datetime="16-12-2014 01:05"> Dec 16, 2014 <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></time>
</header>
<div class="panel panel-default arrow left">

  <div class="panel-body">

    <?= Html::a('Delete','?r=twit/delete-twit&id='.$twits['id'],['class' => 'pull-left btn btn-danger btn-sm']); ?>
    <?= Html::a('Update','#&id='.$twits['id'],['class' => 'pull-left btn btn-primary btn-sm']); ?>


      <div class="comment-post">
          <p style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">
              <?php echo $twits['twit']; ?>
          </p>
      </div>
      <p class="text-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> reply</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<?php  } ?>
```

and here is my controller actionView which i want to get the id value and then send it to actionDeleteTwit :

```
public function actionView($id = null)
{
    echo $id;
    die();
}
```

and here is my actionDeleteTwit which i don't know how to pass the id value to it :

```
public function actionDeleteTwit()
{

    if(Yii::$app->request->get() && Yii::$app->request->get('id')){
        $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
        Twit::deleteTwit($id);
        \yii::$app->response->redirect('?r=twit/index',301)->send();
    }
}
```

(I don't want to use the `Yii::$app->request->get('id')` and I'm trying to use the actionView instead )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change you delete action to a thing like this:

```
public function actionDeleteTwit($id = null)
{
    if(null != $id){
        Twit::deleteTwit($id);
        \yii::$app->response->redirect('?r=twit/index',301)->send();
    }
}
```

As you used this notation in your view action. If more help needed, more information from your problem is needed.

**Update:** You must pass your numeric values in get method (Or more general based on your routing table, your other parameters) as a part of url, i.e. your view file must be like this:

```
<?php
  foreach($twit as $twits){
?>


<header class="text-right">
    <div class="comment-user"> سبحان باقری <i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
    <time class="comment-date" datetime="16-12-2014 01:05"> Dec 16, 2014 <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></time>
</header>
<div class="panel panel-default arrow left">

  <div class="panel-body">

    <?= Html::a('Delete',['/twit/delete-twit', 'id' => $twits['id']],['class' => 'pull-left btn btn-danger btn-sm']); ?>
    <?= Html::a('Update','#&id='.$twits['id'],['class' => 'pull-left btn btn-primary btn-sm']); ?>


      <div class="comment-post">
          <p style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">
              <?php echo $twits['twit']; ?>
          </p>
      </div>
      <p class="text-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> reply</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<?php  } ?>
```

Please consider [Yii2 Guide - Action Parameters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#action-parameters) for more information.